# What should I do to make it work when I press GPIO 19 after code execution?

Tags: python, gpio

```
def door():
    b = GPIO.input(19)
    if b == False:
        GPIO.output(26,False)

    s = GPIO.input(21)
    if s == False:
        GPIO.output(26,True)

door()
```

I want to always work `door()`.
However, it does not work when code is executed and GPIO 19 is pressed.
It works when I press and hold GPIO 19 and execute the code.
What should I do to make it work when I press GPIO 19 after code execution?
There are other def other than the def door so while True should not be used. how can I do it in another way without using while True?

Comment: Seems you need to include the code in an event loop, something like `while True:`. You can find plenty of examples all over the internet, for example https://raspi.tv/2013/rpi-gpio-basics-6-using-inputs-and-outputs-together-with-rpi-gpio-pull-ups-and-pull-downs

Comment: you can use `if not s:` instead of `if s == False:` in python. It was not your problem but have a clean code make debug easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion or cycle while :

```
while True:
    b = GPIO.input(19)
    if b == False:
        GPIO.output(26,False)

    s = GPIO.input(21)
    if s == False:
        GPIO.output(26,True)
```

Comment: I didn't have enough explanation. I'm sorry. There are other def other than the def door so while True should not be used. how can I do it in another way without using  while True?

Answer (score 0):

please use a While cycle :

```
def door():
b = GPIO.input(19)
    if b == False:
        GPIO.output(26,False)

    s = GPIO.input(21)
    if s == False:
        GPIO.output(26,True)

def light():
    b = GPIO.input(19)
    if b == False:
        GPIO.output(26,False)

    s = GPIO.input(21)
    if s == False:
        GPIO.output(26,True)

while True:
    door()
    light()
```